Clicking a specific dropdown filter with puppeteer
I am trying to click the Popular filter button on this website.

I know how to open the dropdown, like:
await page.click('body > div.flex.h-full.flex-col > div > div.relative.flex.h-full.w-full.grow.flex-col.transition-all.duration-200.lg\\:ps-\\[232px\\] > main > div > div.simplebar-wrapper > div.simplebar-mask > div > div > div > div > div > div.flex.items-center.justify-between.gap-4 > div.flex.gap-1.sm\\:gap-2\\.5 > div.relative.cursor-pointer.justify-center.border.text-xs.w-\\[120px\\].sm\\:w-\\[130px\\].dark\\:bg-black.dark\\:text-dark3-secondary.dark\\:border-white.bg-blue-3.text-black.border-black.rounded-full > div > span > span > span');

However, I am struggling to select the correct filter.
Any suggestion on how to do this?
I appreciate your replies.

Please share the page and a [mcve] of your code. There's no way to assist without that information. See this regarding those long browser-generated selectors.
